# BufferedReader / Scanner not working for "\n"

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I'm in the midst of working up a client-server chat application, where the client decides to leave the chat room by keying in "\n". However, String.equals() does not seem to work. While I know BufferedReader.readLine() discards new-line characters, I've tried it with the Scanner class and it also does not work. Am I doing something wrong here?

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String keyboardInput = br.readLine();
            if (keyboardInput.equals("\n")) {
                break;
            }
```

EDIT: Realized that I needed to escape \n with another .

Comment: that's equivalent of an empty string....

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that too, but it doesn't work as well!

Comment: Try if (keyboardInput.equals("")) {
                break;
            }

Comment: i didn't say to try it ... ;) . anyway you might need to word your question a little bit. i don't seem to get what you really want.

Comment: Tried that. Doesn't work.

Comment: @OusmaneDiaw basically, the client is able to leave the chatroom when he types in "\n" into the console. So my code here is to close the socket when it detects \n typed into the console.

Comment: Btw, not cool to downvote without knowing more details man.

Comment: If a user types the 2 characters ``\`` and `n`, then you need to compare to those two characters, but ``"\n"`` is a string with a single *new-line* character, not the two separate characters ``\`` and `n`. To get a ``\`` is a Java string literal, double it, i.e. `"\\n"` is the correct string to compare against.

Comment: @Andreas thanks man, I completely forgot to escape the \!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, realized that I should escape the \n by including a \ before it.